# Как удалить записи из таблицы по Date

Tags: java, sql, spring

```
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from ApiLogEntity a where a.dateRs = ?1")
    public void deleteApiLogEntityByDateRs(Date date);
```

Как написать запрос, который будет удалять записи по Date больше недели?

Answer (score 1):

С нынешней даты вычесть старую. Это будет время которое прошло, сравнить его с количеством мили секунд в недели, если  больше либо равно недели значит уже пора удалять, соответственно берём и удаляем эту запись с этой датой.
Либо на этапе добавления записи в таблицу, сделать столбец с датой окончания действия(удаления), для этого просто к дате создания прибавляем неделю и сохраняем. Далее если надо почистить либо при любой выборке просто проверяем, что дата удаления не равна и не меньше нынешней, в противном случае удаляем. Я так понял с самим запросом, то у вас не должно быть проблем. Просто удалить запись со строкой у которой в процессе проверки вы выявили просрочку по дате.